# javascript undefined value using fetch in function

Tags: javascript, async-await

If I call this function:

```
async function delete_get_note() {
    let query = {
        'command': 'delete_get_content',
        'note_id': input_note_id.value
    }

    let response = await fetch(
            '../api/api.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
                body: JSON.stringify(query)
            }
        );

    let result = await response.json();

    log.innerHTML = result.log;
}
```

`log` displays the content of the json returned by my server. However, if I try to encapsulate the call to `fetch` in a function:

```
async function json_exchange(object) {
    let response = await fetch(
        '../api/api.php',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
            body: JSON.stringify(object)
        });

    return await response.json;
}
```

And call:

```
async function delete_get_note() {
    let query = {
        'command': 'delete_get_content',
        'note_id': input_note_id.value
    }

    let result = await json_exchange(query);

    log.innerHTML = result.log;
}
```

Then `log` displays `undefined`.

What did I get wrong when I tried to put the call to `fetch` in a function ?

Comment: i think you want to return `response.json()` not `response.json`. you also dont need to `return await` you can just `return response.json()` which will return a promise either way because it's an async function

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the sidenote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the parentheses to the json call:

`return await response.json;`

-->

`return await response.json()`

---

**Tip:** You can use `TypeScript` checking to easily detect such errors:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was just that. I am happy and sad at the same time.

Comment: Tip: If you used TypeScript checking, you would have caught this error inside the code editor immediately.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the advice. I am beginning and there is so much to learn, but I will keep that in mind.